# Seeking shortcut to execute a Program with a supplied Local Path

Tags: linux, bash, shortcuts

A program requires local path property to perform correctly.
I'm seeking shortcut command to execute a program with a supplied localPath

For example,

```
cd /usr/local/blogrmis
/usr/local/blogrmis/remote &
```

remote program requires local path @ /usr/local/blogrmis to run.
is there any shortcut which i can do it in 1 line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the program must be run with the current working directory set to the directory containing the program you can combine both commands on one line:

```
 cd /usr/local/blogrmis; ./remote &
```

To shorten this you can create an alias (one-off, or permanently in your shell's .profile file)

```
 alias blogrmis="(cd /usr/local/blogrmis; ./remote &)"
```

then you just type

```
 blogrmis
```

Or create and use a shell-function (see man bash)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`cd /usr/local/blogrmis ; /usr/local/blogrmis/remote &`

Comment: Alternatively, there's `&&` which will only run the second command once the first has shown to work. Although in this case you're suspecting the same folder tree to be present, but just saying so that the reader is aware of the difference...